# How to show data from select2 array from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-select2

I'm quite new with stuff, would be thankful if someone can advice me something. I don't understand how to save an array (workers) from select2 from and how to show them (their names) later on in the created form (which ID they are assigned to).

[image]

So I have 3 tables:

- **tasks:** id, name and so on.
- **workers:** id, firstname, lastname.
- **worker_tasks:** worker_id, task_id.

That's how I create a task (and insert it into tasks table) and also insert a task ID into worker_tasks table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (shortname, projectname, createdby, starting_date, end_date, `description`, workstatus) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
             $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
             $q->execute(array($shortname,$projectname,$createdby,$starting_date,$end_date,$description,$workstatus));
             $task_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
             $sql = "INSERT INTO worker_tasks (worker_id, task_id) value(?, ?)";
             $w = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

So then in this worker_tasks table the worker chosen in this select2 form gets a task id.

```
<select name="worker[]" class="select2 browser-default"
        multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup  label="Konstruktion">
    <?php
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM workers';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo '<option value="'. $row['id']. '"';
echo 'class="left">'. $row['worker_name'] . ' ' . $row['worker_surname'];
echo '</option>';    
} 
Database::disconnect();
?>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup  label="Produktion">
    <?php
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM workers WHERE worker_field = "Produktion"';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo '<option value="'. $row['id']. '"';
echo 'class="left">'. $row['worker_name'] . ' ' . $row['worker_surname'];
echo '</option>';    
} 
Database::disconnect();
?>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

And that's where stuff from my task is shown:

```
    <?php
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE workstatus="In Bearbeitung" ORDER BY id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion animate fadeUp">';
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<div class="collapsible-header" tabindex="0">';
    echo  $row['shortname'];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="collapsible-body pad white-blur lighten-5">';
    echo '<p class="black-text">';
    echo '<b>Projekt:</b>';
    /* echo '<br>'. $row['workers name should be showed here but I wonder how to do that properly?'] . '<br>'; */
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<b>Projekt Bezeichnung:</b>';
    echo '<br>B8 Version 1.2.0';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<b>Aufgabe:</b>';
    echo '<br>'. $row['description'] . '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<b>Mitarbeiter:</b>';
    echo '<br>'. $row['workers_array'] . '<br>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    }
    Database::disconnect();
    ?>
```

Comment: `<!--` only works for html, use `//` for comments in php

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are required to ask a _specific_ question here, explain what _exactly_ is keeping you from getting this implemented. “I want” is not a _question_.

Comment: I have corrected the question a bit.